# How to put a file into another one line by line

Tags: bash, file, text-processing

I have two files with exactly same line numbers. They are like as below:

```
File-A
X1 Y1 Z1 T1
X2 Y2 Z2 T2

File-B
M1 N1
M2 N2
```

So, I want to merge them so that the final file (File-C) will be look as following:

```
X1 Y1 M1 Z1 T1
X2 Y2 M2 Z2 T2
```

So simply, I need to take the first field of each line in File-B and put it as a third field into final file. How can I do that with bash  commands?

**EDIT**

After the provided answer, I tried to merge these files but change the column that comes from the file-B based on the values on that column. So, by following I want file-C as follows:

```
  X1 Y1 "foo" Z1 T1    #if M1 == 3
    X2 Y2 "boo" Z2 T2  # if M2 == 4 
    X3 Y3 "goo" Z3 T3  # if M2 == 2
    X4 Y4 "too" Z4 T4  # if M2 == 1
```

It is guaranteed that M2 will be one of these values.

Comment: I have plenty of questions here eg--> from hereX3 and X4 has come? And M1 and M2 values means their actual values from File-B only right?

Comment: Can you add an example of the **file_b** for the second part of your question? And the desired output too. My understanding of the question: if **M1** (first column, first row of the **file_b**) is equal to **3**, put the **"foo"** into the middle column of the output. If the **M1** is not equal to **3**, for example it is **8**, put this value into the output without changes. **M1** is for first line of the output only. To others lines the same rule, except **M2** (first column, second row) is checked instead **M1**. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following awk and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1 FS $2;b[FNR]=$3 FS $4;next} {print a[FNR],$1,b[FNR]}' File-A File-B
```

Output will be as follows.

```
X1 Y1 M1 Z1 T1
X2 Y2 M2 Z2 T2
```

If you want to take this output into a Input_file named C simply add `> "File-C"` at the end of above command.

Adding non-one liner form of solution too now with explanation of code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                ##FNR==NR condition will be TRUE when first Input_file named File-A is being read. If this condition is TRUE do following.
  a[FNR]=$1 FS $2;      ##Creating an array named a whose index is current line and value is 1st and 2nd columns with a space in between them.
  b[FNR]=$3 FS $4;      ##Creating an array named b whose index is current line number and value is 3rd and 4th column with a space in them.
  next                  ##using next will make sure NO further statements are being used.
}
{
  print a[FNR],$1,b[FNR]##This print statement will be executed when 2nd Input_file named File-B is being read because during first Input_file read it will NEVER come on this statement, so simply printing here array a value with index of current line number then printing 1st column and then printing array b whose index is current line.
}
' File-A File-B         ##Mentioning Input_files here.
```

**EDIT1:** Since OP added a small requirement in actual question itself so adding edited solution too here.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1 FS $2;b[FNR]=$3 FS $4;next} $1==3{val="foo"} $1==4{val="boo"}$1==2{val="goo"} $1==1{val="too"}{print a[FNR],val,b[FNR]}' File-A File-B
```

Comment: thanks It worked! I have limited knowledge on text-processing using linux tool such as awk and I definetely want to learn more. Reading tutorials boring . Do you know a good tutorial for it ?

Comment: @RavingerSingh13 I was waiting to time-limit pass to accept your answer

Comment: @RavingerSingh, although I finished with original question, to conditionally change the column that comes from the second file, I tried the following line `FNR==NR{if ($2 == "1") $2=31; elseif ($2 == "2") $2=32; elseif ($2 == "3") $3=78;a[FNR]=$1 FS $2;b[FNR]=$3 FS $4;next} {print a[FNR],$2,b[FNR]}` based on your answer but it didn't work what might be wrong ?

Comment: Could you please edit the question and let me know then. I will try to edit the post accordingly then.

Comment: @zwlayer, please check my EDIT1, I haven't tested it since no sample data for it, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't work. It prints nothing for that field. I mean output is simply `X1 Y1 Z1 T1`

Comment: I have put conditions to check if $1's value is 4 or 3 or 2 or 1 etc because M1,M2 values comes o $1 only right in File-B? Is it not right? Then kindly let me know by which logic you want foo,boo etc please

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question:

```
paste file_a file_b | awk '{print $1, $2, $5, $3, $4;}'
```

**file_a**

```
X1 Y1 Z1 T1
X2 Y2 Z2 T2
```

**file_b**

```
M1 N1
M2 N2
```

**Output**

```
X1 Y1 M1 Z1 T1
X2 Y2 M2 Z2 T2
```